# Nextcloud session problems

Tags: nginx, nextcloud

I am getting errors in the Nextcloud instance I have been getting `412` responses at random times. I have no idea of the source of this. I have a VPS on Digital Ocean with minimal load on it.

Since almost the first day of my Nextcloud installation I have this issue. It seems that it was there all the time and it is more prominent now during this COVID-19 situation when using Talk during the day.

Logs and relevant information can be seen in [this issue](https://github.com/nextcloud/spreed/issues/3798).

The reason I am posting this here is that it seems to come from Nginx. I get at "radnom" *(I do not know if they are random)* times a 412 error and there is a disconnection. Sometimes the disconnection means complete disconnection that I need to reenter my credentials. This happens to both Firefox and Chrome and in both Windows and Linux.

My Nginx configuration is exactly the same as proposed by the [documentation here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/19/admin_manual/installation/nginx.html).

I have been searching intensively last week and I could not find anything. The strange thing is that I am not getting any error in all the following logs: `nginx`, `nextcloud`, `coturn`, `php`.
The only thing I am getting is a `412` response in the Nginx `access.log`.